# how to remove key when the value is empty in json

Tags: json

I want to remove key when value is null in JSON for example (using JAVA)

```
"attributes": {
                        "csapDescriptionOfNart": {
                            "values": []
                        },
                         "cpimCustomerWishDateOfDelivery": {
                            "alias": "Customer Wish Date Of Delivery",
                            "values": [{
                                "value": "12/21/2016",
                                "source": "SAP",
                                "locale": "en-us"
                            }]
                        }
}
```

In this csapDescriptionOfNart has to removed

```
"attributes": {
                        "cpimCustomerWishDateOfDelivery": {
                            "alias": "Customer Wish Date Of Delivery",
                            "values": [{
                                "value": "12/21/2016",
                                "source": "SAP",
                                "locale": "en-us"
                            }]
                        }
}
```

Comment: JSON is a data-format. Any changes need to be made through whatever you have consuming the JSON. What language are you using?

Comment: Try looking for java json processing with your favorite search engine and come back when you have a question...

Comment: The value you try to remove is not null. It is an empty array, which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: i am using java languagne @Erik

Comment: i want to remove key value array value is empty @gnasher729